# How to filter all the fields in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to filter all the fields in react?
I have written a code which only filters specified fields.

```
 let filteredContacts=this.props.contacts.filter(
         (contact)=>{
           return contact.name.indexOf(this.state.search)!==-1;
         }
       );
```

the above code only returns filtered names...but i want to filter name,age,city work.

this is the data file:

```
export default function(){
  return [{
    key: 1,
    name: 'Steve',
    city: 'Paris',
  }, {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Tim',
    city: 'London',
  }, {
    key: 3,
    name: 'Stella',
    city: 'Bankok',
  }, {
    key: 4,
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Paris',
  }];
}
```

i want to create a search bar which which filters all the fields suppose if i search john then the list of john should be displayed and if i search paris then all the entries which have paris should be displayed..So the code which i have written only searches for name as i have specified name..i want to search the inputed data to search all the fields.

Comment: update the ques with sample data and expected output, it will be easy to help you :)

Comment: @Mayank Shukla i have updated question.

Comment: A simple if statement with indexOf on contact.name and contact.city wouldn't do the trick ? Edit: You can loop on your obj if you want it to be generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter criteria can be the `indexOf` on `Object.values()` like below but it will only give a complete match

```js
var data = [{
    key: 1,
    name: 'Steve',
    city: 'Paris',
  }, {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Tim',
    city: 'London',
  }, {
    key: 3,
    name: 'Stella',
    city: 'Bankok',
  }, {
    key: 4,
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Paris',
  }];
  
  var value = 'Paris'
  var newData = data.filter((obj) => {
      return Object.values(obj).indexOf(value) > -1
  })
  console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fastly tried, do a loop on your keys. Maybe there's a more elegant way.

```
 let filteredContacts=this.props.contacts.filter(
     (contact)=>{
       var found = false;
       Object.keys(contact).map(function(key, index) {
         if (contact[key].indexOf(this.state.search) >= 0)
            found = true;
       }
       return found;
     }
  );
```